# Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angular, metadata, ng-modules

### src/+login/index.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

export const routes=[
  { path:'',component:LoginComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
})
export default class Login {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

### src/app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path:'',component:HomeComponent },
    { path:'login',loadChildren: ()=>System.import("./+login")}
];
```

### error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found
>   for '[object Object]'.
>   ac_vendor<["./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/ng_module_resolver.js"]/NgModuleResolverhttp://127.0.0.1:3000/vendor.bundle.js:13839:23

This problem plagued me for a long time, please help me

Comment: Try removing `default`

Comment: Are there more details with the error message?

Comment: Is it related to `loadChildren()`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use Lazy-Loading

Comment: So if you remove `{ path:'login',loadChildren: ()=>System.import("./+login")}` the error goes away?

Comment: When I request example.com/login the error is displayed

Comment: And when you do it like shown in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#asynchronous-routing?

Comment: @linyimeng Post your `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading from Angular 2.0.x to Angular 4.0.x
Problem was in the syntax of Routes. You need to specify the NgModule that is responsible for display of child page.

Old syntax:
`{ path: 'jobs', loadChildren: () => System.import('./jobs/jobs.module') }`

New syntax:
`{ path: 'jobs', loadChildren: 'app/pages/jobs/jobs.module#JobsModule' }`

(note the *#JobsModule* at the end)